# Using a LDAP InMemoryDirectoryServer to authenticate User with Scala

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, ldap

using scala and the playFramework, I've implemented a simple Login-Logout Routine. Now I want to use LDAP to validate wether username and password are correct.

Instead of setting up a Server I'd like to use the InMemoryDirectoryServer descirbed here https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/in-memory-directory-server.html for Test purposes.

However, I can't find a proper Documentation on how to use it.

I found this blog but it seems to be rather improvised.
http://krishnasblog.com/2013/03/29/incorporating-ldap-with-play-2-x-scala-application/

So far I have:

```
  def start(): InMemoryDirectoryServer = {

    val config = new InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig("dc=com");
    config.setListenerConfigs(new InMemoryListenerConfig("ldapListener", InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 0, null, null, null));
    config.setSchema(null);
    val server = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(config);
    server.startListening();

    server.add("dn: dc=com", "objectClass: top", "objectClass: domain", "dc: com");
server.add("dn: dc=test,dc=com", "objectClass: top", "objectClass: domain", "dc: test");
server.add("dn: dc=roles,dc=test,dc=com", "objectClass: top", "objectClass: domain", "dc: roles");
server.add("dn: cn=group,dc=roles,dc=test,dc=com", "objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames", "cn: group");

server.add("dn: cn=user1,dc=test,dc=com", "objectClass: person", "locale: nl_BE",
  "sn: NormalUser", "memberOf: cn=group,dc=roles,dc=test,dc=com", "userPassword: password");

server.add("dn: cn=user2,dc=test,dc=com", "objectClass: person", "locale: nl_BE",
  "sn: NormalUser", "memberOf: cn=group,dc=roles,dc=test,dc=com", "userPassword: password");


    server
  }
```

My question is: 
How would I, based on this initial configuration, validate a username and password such that it would be like using a real LDAP server.

Is it realy just geting the entry and testing the Strings against each other?

```
val retPass = entry.getAttributeValue("userPassword")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm implementing a LDAP authentication module and I'm using a [public LDAP server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) that has been working very well for testing purposes.

Try to test with the entries of this LDAP.